# How to make 2 concurrent network requests in Golang

Tags: go

I have two functions that make networks requests:

e.g.:

```
func request1() (resultTypeA, error) {
  ....
}

func request2() (requestTypeB, error) {
  ...
}
```

Given that they are two different types, I can't just use one channel.
What is the best pattern to parallelize to calls:

```
resultA, err := request1()
resultB, err := request2()
```

Comment: You may just create two goroutines to make them concurrent.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `sync.WorkGroup`

```
var wg sync.WorkGroup
wg.Add(2)
var resultA resultTypeA, errA error
go func() {
    resultA, errA = request1()
    wg.Done()
}()
var resultB resultTypeB, errB error
go func() {
    resultB, errB = request2()
    wg.Done()
}()
wg.Wait()

if errA != nil {
    return errA
}
if errB != nil {
    return errB
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for error handling? e.g. if any of them returns an error, terminate

Comment: @samol You can check `errA` and `errB` after `wg.Wait()` and do what you want on error.